# PlainSelect and SetOperationList in jsql parser

Tags: java, mysql, jsqlparser

what is the difference between PlainSelect and SetOperationList in jsql parser

Comment: I would guess there is a documentation for that.

Answer (score 2):

**PlainSelect** does represent a simple select statement, like:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
```

while **SetOperationList** represents a set operation using multiple **PlainSelect**s (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_(SQL)).

```
SELECT a FROM mytable
UNION
SELECT b FROM mytable2
```

---

The downvote is not ok, due to the missing javadocs for this classes.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially the thing to keep in mind when parsing them in JSQLParser is that if it is a SetOperationList (i.e. Using UNION INTERSECT etc) - It needs to be parsed differently

`selectTableStatement.getSelectBody().getClass().getSimpleName().equals("PlainSelect")` is key

The error encountered if parsing them as the same is
`net.sf.jsqlparser.statement.select.SetOperationList cannot be cast to net.sf.jsqlparser.statement.select.PlainSelect`

```
private static List<String> extractSelectTableSelectItems(Select selectTableStatement){
    List<String> fields = new ArrayList<>();

    if(selectTableStatement.getSelectBody().getClass().getSimpleName().equals("PlainSelect")) {

        PlainSelect plainSelect = (PlainSelect) selectTableStatement.getSelectBody();
        List<SelectItem> selectItems = plainSelect.getSelectItems();
        for(SelectItem selectItem : selectItems) {
            fields.add(selectItem.toString());
        }
    } else if(selectTableStatement.getSelectBody().getClass().getSimpleName().equals("SetOperationList")) {
        
        SetOperationList setOperationList = (SetOperationList) selectTableStatement.getSelectBody();
        List<SelectBody> selectBodyList = setOperationList.getSelects();
        for(SelectBody selectBody: selectBodyList) {
            PlainSelect plainSelect = (PlainSelect) selectBody;
            List<SelectItem> selectItems = plainSelect.getSelectItems();
            for(SelectItem selectItem : selectItems) {
                fields.add(selectItem.toString());
            }
        }
    }
    
    return fields;
}
```